# Is there a runtime penalty associated with typeclasses?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The title pretty much sums up my question: is there a runtime penalty associated with Haskell's typeclasses, or is it just one of those things (like phantom types) with no runtime consequence whatsoever?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Requiring a typeclass is just like passing an extra argument to the function containing the members of the type class as a data structure, since behind the scenes that is what it desugars into in GHC.

That said, GHC is pretty good at inlining and specializing away code that uses typeclasses to the point where its not a problem, with -O2 a very large percentage of them just disappear, but even without that kind of optimization level passing arguments is pretty cheap.

So the overhead *is* more than a phantom type or newtype, but it isn't very high.

As an aside, the overhead in other compilers can vary. e.g. JHC effectively performs case analysis on the type constructors using a limited form of dependent types, so you pay for the number of constrained type variables, not the number of constraints when working in JHC.

Comment: Passing an extra argument is cheap.  Calling the unknown function in that passed record is very expensive.  So type classes are quite expensive, unless the compiler manages to specialize them away.

Comment: I always appreciate Augustss's answer style.  Providing over-qualified answers and so concise that many askers don't understand their full value (since 2011).  I sometimes feel we should make a bot that always comments on his answers/comments saying "Wow, that's good to know!".

Comment: True, I suppose I should have added the caveat that calling a function from the dictionary you are passed requires at least one, usually 2 indirect jumps, which means pipeline stalls, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am also very interested in this topic. Specifically, I'd like to better understand under what specific conditions would the instance (therefore the final implementation) be undecidable at compile time. Existentials come to mind, but this is an extension to H98. Examples would be very welcome, thanks !

Comment: @Paul R: Polymorphic recursion is one example, but ultimately if I call a method which for instance takes `Ord a` but uses it to build `Ord [a]` for something it calls and it doesn't get inlined, ultimately it has to construct the dictionary at runtime.